# ie clientWidth offsetWidth and jQuery all wrong

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm testing on IE (9 and 8, 7 can do one..)

I'm getting the wrong width reported back to me when I query it. The laptop has the resolution `1366 x 768` and the browser is as large as fits on the screen (I can still see the chrome)

But IE **insists** its actually `1525` wide. Clearly incorrect.

**I've tried**

```
window.outerWidth
document.body.clientWidth
$(window).innerWidth()
$(window).outerWidth()
$(window).width()
$(document).innerWidth()
$(document).outerWidth()
```

All report the same bogus result, is there a known bug here?

[edit]
It works wonderfully in **every single** other browser.

Comment: What is the zoom level of your browser?

Comment: ARGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGH!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @PaulS. Judging by the reaction, you may want to put that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zoom setting of a browser can mean that a different number of pixels is being rendered in the browser to what you might expect based upon your screen's resolution.

Reset IE's zoom to the default 100% and see if the numbers match what you expect now.

Comment: Exactly correct, I was just putting together an answer myself. I'm using this library (edit your answer to include if you want) to detect and warn about zoom levels. https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom